# jquery animate: How can I get the height of element dynamically for animation?

Tags: jquery, height, jquery-animate, slidetoggle

How can I get the height of element dynamically for `animate()`?

This is my code to reveal more hidden text in an element. The problem is that I have to fix the animate height (300px for instance) to a fixed number and the text is constantly changed so I don't know how long it will be.

```
$('.toggle-slide').click(function() {

      var object = $(this);
      var object_target = $('.text-about');
      var target_height = object_target.height();

     object_target.animate({
        height:'300px'
      }, 1500 );


      return false;
 });
```

So I think the actual height of the element should be obtained dynamically then I can pass this parameter into `animate()`.

But how can I get this dynamic height?

Or maybe you have other better ideas?

Here is my testing [link](http://jsfiddle.net/unLBu/2/).

Comment: You get the height of an element in jQuery with [.height]() unless the element is hidden at the time of the call. Then you have to be kind of sneaky about it. Is the dynamic element hidden when you try to get its height?

Comment: yea it is hidden from start as you can see from here - http://jsfiddle.net/unLBu/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.toggle-slide').click(function() {

      var object = $(this);
      var object_target = $('.text-about');
      var target_height = object_target.height('100%').height();

      object_target.height('200px');

      object_target.animate({
        height: target_height + 'px'
      }, 1500 );


      return false;
 });
```

I got it to work by first making it all visible, then taking the height, then putting back to 200px and animating :)

maybe a flicker on slower machines but its an idea